# IPython notebook interface much slower on Safari than Chrome

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am noticing that ipython notebook is slow when using in Safari than when using in Chrome (both on OS X Yosemite). Navigating the directory tree is slow, and opening a new notebook is also slow - you can see the progress bar on the new notebook page loading, as if one were loading a page from a server far away. By contrast opening a new notebook on Chrome is almost instantaneous.

Another thing that I find to be very slow is rendering of a matplotlib figure. With the `%matplotlib inline` command to the notebook, displaying an image on the page takes far longer than on Chrome.

It seems to me that the speed is somehow related to rendering on the screen, rather than to the python backend. Any clues why this could be happening? Should I be changing some configuration? Am I the only one with this issue?

Comment: Same here with my older iMac. With my newer iMac it's the other way around. So Chrome seems to be slower now than Safari. But it's a quite heavy notebook and I have some plug-ins activated. Could be an issue too.